# LinkedIn Share Post URL with parameter

Tags: linkedin-api

I have created a post on my websites when I shared on LinkedIn, it's not showing complete URL of sharing.

Currently, I am using `https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=www.example.com/share/?id=12654`

But When I am sharing with LinkedIn using above its redirect to below URL :

```
www.example.com/share
```

Its removing parameter which passed using id. How I can get the full URL: `www.example.com/share/?id=12654`

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to do [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) with parameters you are feeding to another URL.  So, your link should be `...&url=https%3A%2F%2Fw...`, and not `...&url=https://`.  Your URL also contains a question mark that should be escaped.  Ultimately, your URL should look like this..

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com/share/%3Fid=12654
```

URL encoding is required any time you are sending a URL as an argument to the GET param of another URL.

In case you want to know more: **[Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**

If you are interested in a regularly maintained GitHub project that keeps track of this so you don't have to, check it out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue.